# An easy and short question: does my proof work?

Tags: logic, solution-verification

I was trying to prove the statement in the picture, as well as the proof given in the book.
[My proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBlEj.jpg), and
[The proof in the book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRhlw.jpg).
My proof for this statement was way different from the proof in the textbook(the book I’m using is called A First Course in Mathematical Logic and Set Theory by Michael L. O’Leary). My question should be very easy to answer for people who are experienced dealing with logic.

There have been many times that my proofs don’t match with the proofs in the book, and mine are somehow ALWAYS shorter and less complicated. This is a typical example of that situation, so I’m wondering if my proof is also correct. By the way, I don’t have an instructor or anyone I can talk to about this problem: I’m teaching myself this book and some other parts of math.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: It's truly bizarre that the the textbook would insert a proof by contradiction into this simple proof!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is correct, the author's proof isn't. The application of RAA (3-6) would result in $\lnot\lnot R$ on line 7, which needs an application of DNE to get $R$. DNE isn't necessarily a valid inference rule - so it matters. Having said that, the method the author has used is very handy in certain circumstances and can make proofs much easier to follow/write. The author may also have wanted to highlight a technique that was recently covered in the book.

There are quite a few proof checkers online, so I'd recommend finding one you like. I've included your proof in MathJax to give you an idea on how to format things for future questions. Personally, I avoid fitch style like the plague because I think it's messy, awkward to format, and it doesn't make things clear like a nice set of dependency numbers does, but each to their own lol!

$\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}\fitch{~~1.~P\to R 
 ~~~~\small\text{Given}}{{\fitch{~~2.~P \land Q ~~~~\small\text{Assumption}}{~~3.~P ~~~~\small\text{2, Simp}\\~~4.~R ~~~~\small\text{1, 3, MP}\\~~5.~R \lor S ~~~~\small\text{4, Add}}}\\~~6.~(P \land Q)\to(R\lor S) ~~~~\small\text{2-5 DP (should this be CP?)}}$